# Share ethernet connection to other devices broken (segfault)

Tags: networking, 16.04, hot-spot

I had a connection defined in my Ubuntu (16.04) to share my ethernet connection to other devices using WiFi configured as a hotspot. It worked perfectly well until today. Every time I try to connect to my computer the WiFi breaks and a message appears telling "disconnected" and dies, clicking on the network icon tells me that the WiFi network is not ready. Googling I found that I can reset it using: `sudo service network-manager restart`. After resetting (or rebooting) the WiFi seems to work but breaks again if I try to share my ethernet connection.

Probably, an update during the weekend, broke this feature.

What should I do to? Which command should I run to provide you more information?

Doing a `dmesg` that is the only command I know to check Linux problems, tells me a segmentation fault:

```
[   41.416701] wlo1: deauthenticating from 00:1f:ca:83:2e:a0 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
[   41.429457] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   41.429461] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   41.429462] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   41.429464] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   41.429466] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   41.429467] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   41.429469] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   41.429471] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   41.429472] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   41.429474] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   41.429475] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   41.910282] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   41.916941] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   41.917030] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   42.190963] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.197625] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.197714] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   42.276119] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   42.284963] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[   42.290589] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.297254] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.297342] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   42.569482] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.576158] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.576264] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   42.658173] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   42.660754] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   42.660867] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.667515] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.667604] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   42.939971] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.946627] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   42.946715] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   43.033956] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   43.044973] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[   66.835084] show_signal_msg: 51 callbacks suppressed
[   66.835089] wpa_supplicant[2446]: segfault at 30 ip 00005582e920d582 sp 00007ffe24d6e440 error 4 in wpa_supplicant[5582e919c000+204000]
[   66.988456] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   66.995111] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   66.995199] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
[   67.267469] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   67.274324] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   67.274416] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
```

You can see that I desconnect from a previus wifi connection and when I try to connect from a device it breaks.

Thank you.

Comment: If I try with a WEP password I get the next error using `dmesg`: `[  902.795400] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Error setting PAN parameters (-5)
[  902.795402] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: Command REPLY_WIPAN_WEPKEY failed: FW Error
[  902.795407] wlo1: failed to remove key (0, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-5)
[  902.795673] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested
[  902.795674] iwlwifi 0000:5c:00.0: iwl_trans_wait_tx_queue_empty bad state = 0`